# Not allowed to load local resource: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, backend

I am working on a real-time chat application, and I want to allow users to upload their own images to use as avatars. When a user uploads an image, the backend displays the following URL: file:///C:/fakepath/016CF4E2-65C6-46E1-8C5C-415E74970948.jpeg. When I log in to the app and check the console, however, I am greeted by the following message: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/016CF4E2-65C6-46E1-8C5C-415E74970948.jpeg. I was testing, and I then decided to change the input type from file to URL, and I then pasted the random address of a google image, and then when I loaded it back into the app the image had disappeared. Is there any way to allow for user-uploaded images to be displayed? I am using stream-chat API if that also helps, as well as Heroku and nodejs.

Comment: please add some code to your request , like that it's too dificult too know where the problem is

Comment: It's not quite clear but I guess you are saving the files in your file system. If that is the case React can't access a remote file system like that. That would be a major security issue. What you need to do is read the file inside Node.js and send it to React as a blob or base64 string. If everything you do is local, then use a FileReader inside React to read properly the image but this won't work on production.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the input as `type="file"`. The user is picking a file from their disk. It won't have a URL.

`fakepath` comes from trying to treat the file input as a string instead of as a file. If you are using JavaScript, don't use the `value` property of the field as it is only useful for informational and debugging purposes. If you are submitting a form then it needs to be able to handle file inputs (and the default `enctype` doesn't).

Upload the image to a server. How you do this depends on your approach, if it is with a form then the `enctype` attribute needs to be set to [multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean), if it is with Ajax then you should start with a [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

On the server, parse the request (the specifics depend on your server side environment) and save the file somewhere.

Give the file a URL (either by saving it to a place that static files are served from or by having another server side process read the file (from wherever you saved it) on demand).